# what is firebase 16.0.5 min api level

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Google's apis are terriblely documented

I'm struggling with a problem since i decided to update the dependencies from my app (why god whyyyyyy) thinking that newer versions meant better ones

Looks that firebase no longer accepts API lvl 16

the same method i was using berore and working stoped working.
and this method works fine at API 27

the method is:

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        publishProgress();
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
System.out.println("error!!");
                   //do stuff
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So, token is my custom token authentication and works fine
this method works perfectly for api lvl 27
but on api lvl 16 it simple stuck... not even print `error` or crashes the app... simple the call gets lost inside firebase inner method

i looked all google docs from firebase and there is NOWHERE in the offical page that says "this is the latest version of firebase sdk... this is the min requirements"

what i found is this post from a blog but very old
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html

does anyone know the min firebase requ?

Answer (score 0):

The blog post is correct.  The minimum API level is still currently 14.  That is also very likely increase in the future.  What you're experiencing sounds more a bug than a min API level restriction.  You should [file a bug report](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if you have a straightfoward way to reproduce this.

Comment: it must be related to api lvl and google play services... it's not possible to run firebase on the android studio lvl 16 available image

Comment: As I said, please file a bug report with reproduction steps. The min API level is 14, and if it doesn't work on that or higher, it might be a bug.